# biber citekey order error

Tags: biber

I keep getting the error when compiling my thesis:

```
Entity: line 1957: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document <bcf:citekey order="17">Bell20 ^
```

when I compile my file and I found that the citekey order actually starts at 8 instead of 1 in the .bcf file.

However, if I compile the file in a document with only `\nocite{*}` and `\printbibliography` as below biber works fine and is able to print out all the reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\addbibresource{memsb.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by compiling the file in an empty document? Have you tried deleting all generated files and recompiling? Can you post a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem? What is on line 1957?

Comment: Maybe you might like to examine the entry `Bell20` (or starting with `Bell20`) further, maybe there are some evil characters lying round there.

Comment: Plus, I would not worry too much about the internal order of the citekeys as long as the order is not messed up in the output document.

Comment: as I mentioned this problem only happens when you cite my references in the document that I want but it works completely fine with the MWE above

Comment: The mwe above certainly doesn't compile - you don't load biblatex. Beside this a document that works is not really useful to find out why another document doesn't work.

Comment: Well, first of all, make sure to clean the temporary files and recompile from scratch. What happens if you delete the entry `Bell20` from your `.bib` file? Does your big document compile then? Does your actual document contain any modifications to `biblatex` or anything else that could interfere with it? (I seem to remember from an earlier post of yours that your `.bib` file used to contain some characters not recognised by LaTeX, that might be a problem here as well.)

Comment: I guess the characters problem are solved as everything can be complied with the MWE without any error or warning. It is not the problem with the entry Bell20 as I notice that biber keep pointing to that particular line 1957. Removing that entry gives the error "Entity: line 1958: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document ^" without pointing to any particular entry

Comment: What does the `.bcf` file contain in line 1958, is there really some garbage there? Maybe you can upload your `.bcf` file and `.bib` file, so we can have a look at it. Or just post the important sections of it above. Have you deleted the temporary files (all of them)? Does `biber` give any errors/warnings/hints? Can you show us the preamble of your actual document or prepare a real M(not)WE?

Comment: The error might also not lie with `Bell20` but the entry before that one (worth a try).

Comment: It seems to be alright now. The error was shown during the first pdflatex but not showing up anymore after clicking biber->pdflatex x2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because was solved by using the appropriate sequence of commands: `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` (see comment above).